# Конфликты в svn/git

Tags: svn, git, netbeans

Доброе время суток.

Над проектом работает 2 человека.
Допустим что они работали в одном файле.
Один закоммитил изменения
Другой не сделав апдейт тоже сделал коммит

В данной ситуации при работе с SVN в ide(net beans) возникнет ошибка - что верно.
В GIT все уйдет. И с GIT приходиться решать конфликт уже на самом сервере.

Как этого избежать? Возможно какая-то проверка на то, что если возник конфликт - отмена Pull...?
Как держать в чистоте ветки, как следить за тем чтобы каждый git pull был результирующим, ну или в крайнем случае оповещал что возник конфликт.

Comment: У меня создалось впечатление, что вы оперируете терминами предметной области, в которой вообще ничего не понимаете. Почитайте [книжку](http://git-scm.com/book/ru).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в git коммиты локальные. И конфликта нет. А в svn коммиты "удаленные". Если очень формально посмотреть, то svn commit = git add . && git commit && git push.

Но если один пользователь запушил свои изменения, то другому не даст запушить, если он не выкачал изменения с сервера командой git pull (если изменений нет, то делать ее не нужно) и не решил конфликты. Но git он умный, он часто умеет кофликты сам решать.

> И с GIT приходиться решать конфликт уже на самом сервере.

Это не так. Проблему на сервере решают только в том случае, если разработчики были пьяны и сломали все. Но обычно такое заканчивается втыком.

А так, все проблемы решает тот, кто решил запушить изменения.

> Как этого избежать?

Этого не нужно стараться избежать. Как раз для этого git и придуман. А избежать стараются те, которые работают напрямую с кодом. и только время от времени бекапят.

> Возможно какая-то проверка на то, что если возник конфликт - отмена Pull...?

Если при pull git не сможет решить конфликт - он сам об этом скажет и не будет делать pull. (Но сделает перед этим fetch и следующие pull пройдут быстрее - с сервера не нужно ничего будет выкачивать)

> Как держать в чистоте ветки, как следить за тем чтобы каждый git pull был результирующим, ну или в крайнем случае оповещал что возник конфликт.

Общение, общение и ещё раз общение. Возник конфликт - пошел поговорил. Можно всегда договориться.

Comment: Добавлю, что использование локальных feature-веток с последующим сливанием их в общую, также способствует наведению порядка в работе и взаимодействии.

Кроме того никто не мешает написать скрипт типа git_safe_commit, который будет последовательно делать git pull и git commit.

Comment: нет никакого смысла в подобном скрипте. Ведь pull сложно сделать, если есть незакомиченные данные (и это правильно).

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за развернутый ответ.

-Если при pull git не сможет решить конфликт-он сам скажет и не будет делать pull-

В том то и дело, что pull - это fetch+merge. И если при merge возник конфликт, то пока не исправишь его, гит будет ругаться на то что есть незакомиченные файлы(именно на сервере). поэтому приходится идти на сервер, смотреть status(видим что есть незакомеченные) править конфликт, делать коммит и иногда даже пуш(!с сервера)...в общем где-то есть недопонимание. Но все равно спасибо за ответ!

Comment: если у Вас есть незакоммиченные файлы на сервере, то вы что то делаете неправильно. fetch - он просто выкачивает с сервера к Вам. merge - он также локальный. Обе эти команды не модифицируют сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно завести правило: сначала апдейт, потом коммит. А в качестве наказания - заставлять мержить. Таким образом, локализовываться конфликт будет на компьютере разработчика, а не на сервере.

Comment: Блин, ну это же система автоматизации работы. Загружать разработчика тем, о чем он на самом деле задумываться не должен - это значит уменьшать его производительность.

Comment: Ну так в чем же проблема? Сделал апдейт, проконтролировал, что проект собрался, коммит. Если есть конфликт - попытался смержить автоматически. Удалось - коммит, не удалось - делай руками, затем коммит.

Система-то автоматизирует накопление информации, может кое-какие конфликты решать (мержить файл, если два разработчика разные его части редактировали), но чудес не бывает, она не может предсказывать желания.

Апдейт перед коммитом - это правило. Хотя, есть такие VCS, как Mercurial(Hg), где у каждого разработчика локальный реп, который можно синхронизировать с сервером по мере надобности.

Comment: > она не может предсказывать желания.
и тут же
> при работе с SVN в ide(net beans) возникнет ошибка - что верно. В GIT все уйдет

Comment: @Free_ze

> сначала апдейт, потом коммит. 

То есть, поменял код, сделал git pull, потом git add. + git commit?

Comment: > Хотя, есть такие VCS, как Mercurial(Hg), где у каждого разработчика локальный реп

В git у вас как раз и есть локальный реп.